# long hex string to integer in python

Tags: python, type-conversion

I receive from a module a string that is a representation of an long int

```
>>> str = hex(5L)
>>> str
'0x5L'
```

What I now want is to convert the string str back to a number (integer)

int(str,16) does not work because of the L.

Is there a way to do this without stripping the last L out of the string? Because it is also possible that the string contains a hex without the L ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even just use:

```
>>> str = hex(5L)
>>> long(str,16)
5L
>>> int(long(str,16))
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`str.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip); It works for both cases:

```
>>> int('0x5L'.rstrip('L'),16)
5
>>> int('0x5'.rstrip('L'),16)
5
```

Or generate the string this way:

```
>>> s = '{:#x}'.format(5L)  # remove '#' if you don' want '0x'
>>> s
'0x5'
>>> int(s, 16)
5
```